# Calculate DIC from WinBUGS output

Tags: bugs

Has anyone ever tried to calculate DIC "manually" from WinBUGS output? I tried for the simplest linear model, and could get exact the same Dbar, but always a bit different Dhat.
I think Dhat calculation is just -2(log(likehood(posterior mean of parameters))). Any clue about that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Are you asking on DIC, Dhat or both?